# R: matrix from large table

Tags: r, matrix

I have a fairly big table, here is a sample:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(ID = 1:5, area = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), ERC = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a = c(33, 34, 35, 38, 39), b = c(38, 41, 45, 
8, NA), c = c(53, 35, 38, 39, 53), d = c(32, 33, 65, 36, 34)), .Names = c("ID", 
"area", "ERC", "a", "b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create a matrix of the absence / presence of observation. The result should look like this:

```
dput(result)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2), `32` = c(1, 0), `33` = c(1, 1), 
    `34` = c(0, 1), `35` = c(0, 1), `37` = c(0, 0), `38` = c(0, 
    0), `41` = c(1, 0), `53` = c(0, 1), `54` = c(1, 0)), .Names = c("ID", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "37", "38", "41", "53", "54"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

As column I have the factor (observations) and 1 means presence, 0 means absence.

Is there a way to do it without to produce a simple matrix column per column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(DF, id.vars = c("ID", "area", "ERC")), 
  ID ~ value, fill = 0, fun.aggregate = length)
#  ID 8 32 33 34 35 36 38 39 41 45 53 65 NA
#1  1 0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
#2  2 0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
#3  3 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
#4  4 1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
#5  5 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible way using basic R.

Input data:

```
input
  ID area ERC  a  b  c  d
1  1    6   1 33 38 53 32
2  2    6   1 34 41 35 33
3  3    6   1 35 45 38 65
4  4    6   1 38  8 39 36
5  5    6   1 39 NA 53 34
```

Apply an easy function `f` to each row using `apply`:

```
unique_n<-unique(as.numeric(unlist(input[,c(4:7)])))
f<-function(input_1,unique_n)
{
return(as.numeric(unique_n  %in% input_1[c(4:7)]))
}
count_n<-t(apply(input,1,f,unique_n=unique_n))
colnames(count_n)<-unique_n
cbind(ID=input[,1],count_n)
     ID 33 34 35 38 39 41 45 8 <NA> 53 32 65 36
[1,]  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0 0    0  1  1  0  0
[2,]  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  0 0    0  0  0  0  0
[3,]  3  0  0  1  1  0  0  1 0    0  0  0  1  0
[4,]  4  0  0  0  1  1  0  0 1    0  0  0  0  1
[5,]  5  0  1  0  0  1  0  0 0    1  1  0  0  0
```